# Finding font-weight value for span[2] element in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

Is there a way to verify that element 'Adam Slodowy' is bold in Selenium IDE?

This is the fragment of site code:

...

```
<div class='thread-content-row.thread-content-row-1'>
    <div class='thread-content-row-left'>
    <div class='thread-content-row-right'>
        <div class='discussion-info'>
            <b>Daria Ogrodowska</b>
            do 
            <span>super</span>
            ,
            <span>Adam Slodowy</span>
        </div>
        <div class="discussion-content"> bla bl balkjbasdfsdfsdfdsfsdf sdfsdf sdf sdf </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to use verifyEval command:

**Command:** verifyEval

**Target:** var elem = window.document.querySelector("div.thread-content-row.thread-content-row-1 > div.thread-content-row-right > div.discussion-info span"); window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("font-weight");

**Value:** 700

but I have no idea how in querySelector refer to second span - querySelector("div.thread-content-row.thread-content-row-1 > div.thread-content-row-right > div.discussion-info span[2]") doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It is really much more practical for a human person to check styles as even if it was bold it could look really bad and Selenium wouldn't be able to tell if it looked "bad" or not.

That being said, you would probably want to utilize xpath query on this one.

```
    xpath=//span[contains(text(), 'Adam Slodowy')
```

or if you have more than one of those in your web page.

```
    xpath=//div[@class='discussion-info']/span[contains(text(), 'Adam Slodowy')
```

the // indicates to look through the web page for an element that matches whatever follows.  Which is very beneficial so that you don't have to include entire xpath which is very fragile if any of the structure changes.